# Match status bar colour with most predominant colour of art Material Design Android

Tags: android, material-design

I was wondering if there was some kind of library/api or way to match the status bar colour with some imagery just like in the Whatsapp material design update.

Example [here](http://www.androidpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/nexus2cee_whatsapp-material-4.png) and [here](http://www.androidpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/nexus2cee_whatsapp-material-6.png).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you support lib and material theme ? but you can do this in api > 21

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I got it, but you can extract dominant colors in an image with the [Palette support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-palette).

It lets you extract, from a given Bitmap, six colors that you might need:

- Vibrant
- Vibrant Dark
- Vibrant Light
- Muted
- Muted Dark
- Muted Light

See also [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette.html) for reference.